# Is every linear transformation also technically a change of basis matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

I don't really see the difference between a linear transformation and a change of basis matrix.

Let's take this formulation:

$$ Ax = v$$

I can interpret it in two different ways.

1.) The matrix $A$ encodes a linear transformation that converts vector $x$ to vector $v$.

2.) The matrix $A$ is a change of basis matrix whose span includes the vector v. Scaling the new basis $A$ by the values stored in $x$, followed by linearly combining the basis, will give us $v$.

Could all linear transformations also be considered as a change of basis?

Edit: A comment pointed out that a basis by definition must be a set of linearly independent vectors. So not all linear transformations are a change of basis. **In that case, what's the point of a change of basis matrix?** It just seems like a label for a specific type of linear transformation.

Comment: The matrix for a change of basis has to be invertible. BUt not every linear transformation (equivalently its matrix representation) is invertible. So the answer is no.

Comment: So you're saying that if the matrix A is made up of vectors that are not linearly independent, then it's just a linear transformation and not a change of basis.

Answer (score 2):

In the setting of abstract (finite-dimensional, real) vector space $V$ and a linear transformation $T:V\to V$ on $V$, there is no notion of matrices involved.

If you choose an ordered basis $\beta$, then $T$ can be *represented* as an $n\times n$ matrix $[T]_{\beta}$.

On the other hand, if you have two bases $\alpha$ and $\beta$, given any vector $x\in V$, the two different coordinates of $x$ (wrt $\alpha$ and $\beta$),  $[x]_\alpha$ and $[x]_\beta$ are related by a matrix $A_{\alpha}^\beta$:
$$
[x]_\alpha=A_{\alpha}^\beta[x]_{\beta}\tag{1}
$$
This matrix $A_{\alpha}^\beta$ is a linear transformation on $\mathbb{R}^n$, where $n$ is the dimension of $V$. One can show that  $A_{\alpha}^\beta$ must be invertible. So the answer to your question in the title is no, since no every linear transformation (and thus its matrix under any basis) is invertible.

The change-of-basis matrix gives you a formula that expresses the coordinates relative to one basis in terms of coordinates relative to the other basis.